# Trying to call php function with ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass some variables to a php file with ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var id = this.id;
            var name=this.name;
            console.log(id+" "+name);
            $.ajax({
                  type: 'GET',
                  url: 'utility.php',
                  dataType: 'text',
                  data: {id: id, name: name},
                  success: console.log('aa'),
                  //error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){ console.log( errorThrown ); },
                  //complete: alert(id+' '+name)
            }); // Ajax Call
        }); //event handler
    }); //document.ready
```

```html
<?php
warning('getting something');
if($_GET['id'] && $_GET['name']){
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 $name=$_GET['name'];
 if($id=='delete'){
  my_remove($name);
 }
 if($id=='modify'){
  retrieve($name);
  my_remove($name);
  modify($name);
 }
}
else {
 warning('unable to get information');
}

function my_remove($name){
 warning('deleting');
 //mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `book`.`".$page."` WHERE `".$page."`.`name` =\'".$name."\'");
 //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$name');</script>";
}

function modify($name){
 warning('modified');
}

function retrieve($name){
 warning('fetching');
}

function warning($message){
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}

?>
```

The .js part seems to run smoothly, it sets the name and id as it should and returns a success message, but nothing else happens, not even the alert('getting something') which should run regardless of parameters.
Printing out the data gives [object Object] which I'm not even sure what it means.
Please help!

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: it's not clear where you alert the response text

Comment: in the php warning func

Comment: no you have to catch the response and alert it then

Comment: sorry, i don't think I understand what you're saying

Comment: I tried to explain in the answer.Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your php script runs in the background with your ajax call, I don't think the alert code in that page will work. Instead try returning the plain text to the ajax function and alert it there

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var id = this.id;
            var name=this.name;
            console.log(id+" "+name);
            $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'utility.php',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: {id: id, name: name},

            }).done(function(text){
               alert(text);
            }); // Ajax Call
        }); //event handler
    }); //document.ready
```

and your php file like this.I changed your `warning` function

```
<?php
warning('getting something');
if($_GET['id'] && $_GET['name']){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $name=$_GET['name'];
    if($id=='delete'){
        my_remove($name);
    }
    if($id=='modify'){
        retrieve($name);
        my_remove($name);
        modify($name);
    }
}
else {
    warning('unable to get information');
}

function my_remove($name){
    warning('deleting');
    //mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `book`.`".$page."` WHERE `".$page."`.`name` =\'".$name."\'");
    //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$name');</script>";
}

function modify($name){
    warning('modified');
}

function retrieve($name){
    warning('fetching');
}

function warning($message){
    echo $message;
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm getting the first message. I'll try alerting the data to see what happens.

Comment: That helped with this problem, thanks a lot. But now I get only 1 alert instead of getting an alert after each message.

Comment: ajax doesn't work that way. make all your messages in an array and use json here to alert one by one

Answer (score 1):

you're using GET not POST so under the line

```
 if($_GET['id'] && $_GET['name']){
```

should be get, not post as you have it

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$name=$_GET['name'];
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but as i've said i tried using both post and get, and still nothing happened. Thank you for your time, but that is not the issue (I checked again to make sure). I'll correct it right away.

Comment: are you getting the 'aa' in the console ?

Comment: I know you probably have but just to double check...have you named the php file with the php extension ?

Comment: try moving the warning function to the top of the php file, it's calling the function before it's declared.

Comment: did you move the warning func ?

Comment: Tried moving all the functions to the top, with warning being first, still nothing.

Comment: before the php opening tag do a script tag with an alert to make sure the file is being called properly.